# AOL OpenID?

Tags: php, openid, aol

I'm trying to implement OpenID on my site. I've got Google, Yahoo! and ClaimID working so far, but AOL tells me "Invalid devId or Site not registered.". So how do I register my site and/or get a devID and pass it along? I'm using JanRain/PHP OpenID. AOL's dev blog is just a mess.

Comment: Please refer this link http://dev.aol.com/article/2007/integrating_openauth_into_java

Comment: Little late... problem was that AOL's service was down, but this might be useful to someone else, so +1 for that (even though I mentioned PHP, not Java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be related, but it looks like AOL's OpenID may be having issues right now, I had to switch to another provider to log into SO.

Answer (score 2):

AOL is only an OpenID 1.x Provider, whereas the others you mentioned are 2.0 providers (I'm not sure about ClaimID).  I think Janrain's PHP library can handle interop with either version, but in your investigation just be aware of the potential difference there.

Comment: Oh... I wasn't aware of that. Maybe I need to change some setting for backwards compatibility? I'll look into this, thanks.

Comment: It just came out that AOL is trying to upgrade to OpenID 2.0. It looks like they got something wrong and they're working to correct it. I'd sit tight if I were you and see what they do. It's probably not something on your end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have fixed itself. I can now log in with AOL with no changes to my code.